# performance in linear algebra with python

Tags: python, c, performance, numpy, blas

Benchmarks of different languages and related questions are everywhere on the Internet. However, I still cannot figure out an answer of whether I should switch to C in my program.

Basically, The most time consuming part in my program involves a lot of matrix inverse and matrix multiplication. I have several plans:

1. stick with numpy.
2. use C with LAPACK/BLAS.
3. rewrite my python program and change the most time consuming part into C and then use python to call C.

I know numpy is just something wrapped around LAPACK/BLAS. So will 2 or 3 be substantially(500%) faster than 1?

Comment: `cython` actually can be regarded as another language. That's not what I want.

Comment: You're going to have to show us what you're doing and how you're using NumPy. For linear algebra operations, NumPy is just calling down to the optimised LAPACK/BLAS routines (assuming they're on your system) - you're unlikely to get much faster than those. Hand-written C code is likely to much slower than calling these routines.

Comment: @ajcr, edited accordingly

Comment: You can have a look into sagemath . Its based on python and has a lot of stuff included. For my part I use it for big matrix multiplication in GF(2^8).

Comment: Profile your current code - if are spending almost all of your time inside BLAS/LAPACK routines then you will see essentially no performance benefit  from options 2 or 3. One rare scenario where it *might* make sense to re-write some portion of your code in C would be if you are calling BLAS/LAPACK routines a lot of times on many small matrices. In practice you should probably be thinking about whether the efficiency of your algorithm can be improved, whether you are linked against the fastest possible BLAS/LAPACK implementation, and possibly whether you could benefit from using the GPU.

Comment: You mention that you are doing a lot of matrix inversions - if these are to solve linear systems of equations then you are [Doing It Wrong](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/), and you should be using factorization (e.g. `np.linalg.solve`) instead. Without knowing anything about your actual code I can't make any more specific recommendations.

Comment: @ali_m good point. But how can I check how much time I spend in BLAS/LAPACK routines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to ask a very similar question when i saw yours. I have tested this question from various directions. From quite some  time I am trying to beat `numpy.dot` function by my code.

I have large complex matrices and their multiplication is the primary bottleneck of my program. I have tested following methods

1. simple c code.
2. cython code with various optimizations, using cblas.
3. python 32 bit and 64 bit versions and found that 64 bit version is 1.5-2 times faster than the 32 bit.
4. ananconda's MKL implementation but no luck there also.
5. einsum for the matrix multiplication
6. python 3 and python 2.7 are same python 3 @ operator is also same
7. `numpy.dot(a,b,c)` is marginally faster than `c=numpy.dot(a,b)`

by far the numpy.dot is the best. It beat every other method, sometimes marginally (einsum) but mostly significantly.

During my research i come across one article namely
[Ultrafast matrix multiplication](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/boyko/pubs/MatrixMult_SURJ_2004.pdf) which tells that apple's altivec implementation can multiply 2500x2500 matrix in less than a second. On my PC with intel core i3 4th generation 2.3 GHZ 4 gb ram it took 73 seconds using numpy.dot hence I am still searching for faster implementation on PC.

Comment: 73 seconds is still quite a long time for dotting two 2500x2500 float matrices together. I suspect you are probably using a slow, single-threaded BLAS implementation. The same dot product takes ~650ms on my laptop when numpy is linked against multithreaded OpenBLAS, but ~16 seconds when linked against the reference CBLAS implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have just checked my code again and found that the above timings were for integer matrices, for float 64 matrices it reduced to 270 ms (anaconda 3 64 bit with python 3.5). I will be more careful with data types while working with matrices. But still the numpy dot is the best.

Comment: BLAS and LAPACK only support floating point matrices. For matrix multiplication with other dtypes, numpy will fall back on [its own C implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1006), which will be much slower.